# How to compare an array to a reversed one and check if their values match?

Tags: c, string

I wrote a program that reverses an array with the `strrev()` function and checks if its values matches the original one, sort of a palindrome. When the values match, it prints `Palindrome`, else, `Not a palindrome`.

But when I compare them, and the values don't match, it still prints `Palindrome`.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 100

void palindrom(char string[]);

int main()
{
    char string[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };

    printf("Enter string (max length 100 chars): ");
    fgets(string, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    if(string[strlen(string)-1] == '\n') { string[strlen(string)-1] = 0; }
    palindrom(string);

    return (0);
} 

void palindrom(char string[])
{
    int check = 0;
    check = strcmp(strrev(string), string);
    if (check == 0)
    {
        printf("Palindrome");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("Not a palindrome");
    }
}
```

What's my problem?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to make a copy. E.g. `char *copy = strdup(string); .. `check = strcmp(strrev(copy), string);`... `free(copy);`

Comment: Also `char string[MAX_LEN] = { 0 };` --> `char string[MAX_LEN + 1] = { 0 };`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, the function: `fgets()` will not overrun that input buffer and will properly insert  the NUL byte inside the limits of the input buffer, so no need to make the input buffer any longer than MAX_LEN

Comment: @user3629249 See `printf("Enter string (max length 100 chars): ");`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  I looked at that and see it as the OP not realizing exactly how `fgets()` works.  (will input any newline and insert a NUL byte, so the user can not  enter a full 100 characters with out the length of the input buffer being (at least) 2 bytes longer than the max allowed and the parameter to fgets() being MAX_LEN+1.  But all that is a corner case and not specific to the OPs question.

Comment: @user3629249 When `100` characters are entered newLine are not stored in the buffer. Also, you do not need to store newlines. So `100 + 2` is not necessary.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY,  I see where you are coming from.  So your correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `strrev`.

Here's a program in C that will do what you're testing for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
   char a[100], b[100];

   printf("Enter the string to check if it is a palindrome\n");
   fgets(a, 100, stdin);

   strcpy(b,a);
   strrev(b);

   if (strcmp(a,b) == 0)
      printf("Entered string is a palindrome.\n");
   else
      printf("Entered string is not a palindrome.\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know this is a silly example, but I would advise against using gets without disclosure that it is a deprecated and that the user should never using it in the real world.

Comment: You shouldn't use gets(), is it possible to use fgets() here?

Comment: @FernandoCoelho I agree with you, I changed my example to the code using fgets()

Answer (score 4):

From what I can tell `strrev` may modify the original string as well, so you need to copy it.

Answer (score 1):

Since others have clarified what the problem is, I would like to point that it would be faster to check if s[0] == s[len-1], s[1] == s[len-2], until half (rounded up) of the string has been checked.

This would require no extra memory, no copy and half as many comparisons.
Something along the lines of:

```
void palindrom(char string[])
{
    int len = strlen(string) - 1;
    int i, limit = len/2 + (len % 2);
    for (i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        if (string[i] != string[len-i]){
            printf("Not a palindrome\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Palindrome\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function fails because `strrev` modifies the string. You effectively always compare the reversed string to itself.

Here is an alternate function that does not modify the string:

```
void palindrom(const char *str) {
    for (size_t i = 0, j = strlen(str); i < j; i++, j--) {
        if (str[i] != str[j - 1]) {
            printf("Not a palindrome\n");
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("Palindrome\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `strrev` to test for a palindrome the following function detects a palindrome just fine without using non-standard C functions:

```
int ispalindrome(char *str, int len)
{   
    char *p = &str[0];
    char *q = &str[len - 1];
    do
    {
        if(p >= q)
        {
            return 1;
        }
    } while (*p++ == *q--);
    return 0;
}
```